# ready made sugar syrup

Tags: baking

Lorraine Pascal made some macaroons, and added a readymade sugar syrup. Would this be liquid glucose or sugar syrup made earlier and stored. I know how to make sugar syrup, but a ready made one would be much easier when making several flavours.

Comment: The question here isn't very clear - what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

Lorraine evidently used the Italian meringue method of making *macarons*. Italian meringue uses hot sugar syrup, not glucose syrup. As you can see from [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37649/does-simple-syrup-require-refrigeration), sugar syrup can be kept for a few days in the refrigerator. Simple syrup is available ready made for use in cocktails, but do see William Shakespeare's notes in the commments.

Comment: Simple syrup is indeed available ready-made -- it's usually sold near other cocktail supplies. It does seem a little silly to spend a few bucks on something that you can make in a few minutes for pennies, but in any case the syrup used for meringue is more concentrated than the 1:1 sugar to water ratio in simple syrup. Perhaps you'd get to the right concentration by the time the syrup reaches the right stage (248 degrees F), but that'd just take longer.

Comment: Ah, that rings a bell. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Simple syrup recipes vary depending on source, from a 1:1 sugar-water ratio by volume to a 2:1 sugar-water ratio *by weight* (which is something close to 2.3:1 by volume).  I'd have to assume that any competent baker is measuring and making their own syrup; so should you, rather than relying on absurdly priced ready-made stuff.  Producing multiple flavors at home is as easy as splitting a large batch of syrup into several vessels.

Comment: If you are assuming Italian meringue, then readymade syrup is moot. You cannot reheat readymade syrup and have it keep its thickness, you'll evaporate too much. Unless the meringue works with cold syrup (and it will be less stable then, because it doesn't cook the eggwhite into shape), the syrup is easier to prepare right away than to buy and heat up to the exact temperature needed.